# In cloud9 IDE, text in terminal cannot correctly be selected to copy, the position is actually on the left

Tags: cloud9-ide, cloud9, aws-cloud9

This is where I choose:

[image: I thought the text I selected JPG]

Actually, I select this:

[image: Actually selected text JPG]

How to fix this, or it's just a bug?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Is it related to programming itself or to working with some program?

Comment: It's clearly about the ide itself, it cannot work correctly. Text in C9's terminal cannot be correctly copied. There's nothing to do with programming or some program.

Comment: Then you need to clarify your question. We cannot guess what "where I choose" and "I select this" means

Comment: Ooh, that's necessary pics, but I still don't get enough reputation to post them.

Comment: I have had a look at the pictures from the beginning, but I don't have a clue what they mean

Comment: Okay, you know now???

Comment: No, you have not shared any more context yet. According to these images, the first image comes from a terminal and the second does not. But that does not solve the mystery what your problem is

Comment: Why should I paste in a terminal? Can you see "copy"? It's clealy easier to edit in a editor, but not a terminal.

Comment: And sadly, you don't want to help me understand your problem. If you want to get help, you shoud provide more context instead of being rude

Comment: I think my problem is quite clear, you just cannot understand it.

Comment: If it was quite clear, why would I waste my time asking you to be more precise about it, when you don't want to clarify? SO is not a private support chat, but a page that should help others learn from your problems and the solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple things that could be at play. Cloud9 uses the [Ace Editor](https://ace.c9.io/) which is not a standard text box. You NEED to use a monospaced font with Ace as otherwise the text selections might not line up with what's being selected (since this is built on an HTML5 canvas).

Additionally, Cloud9 does use a nonstandard clipboard in order to facilitate Ace. Make sure you copy with Ctrl + c and paste with Ctrl + v as otherwise you may use the system's default clipboard (so an older block of text may be used instead).

Comment: Thank you very much. I've changed the terminal font before. It works correctly after I reset fonts to default.